# Should fragments define in independent files?

Tags: android, fragment

Android fragments can be embed in Activity files as public static inner class.
Or define in independent files.
What is the better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By common sense, I'd implement them as separate files. I do so, for a better code maintenance.
I only use a class in a class or a class into an activity (or fragment) if it's only used in that place and serves as a helper for that,
I normally separate all classes, activities and fragments and I prefix them with CLS_, ACT_ and FRG_ for a better separation and a quicker access in editing my code.